# How to make git ignore a sub directory group with gitignore pattern?

Tags: git

I've a directory `projects/` in root directory. the root directory is added to git. in projects I've several subdirectories. But I want to track only `projects/admin` not `projects/x` nor `projects/y`. What ignore rule I need to write in `.gitignore` ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use a negative ignore clauses, e.g.:

```
project/*
!project/admin
!project/admin/*
```

Comment: If I add only `!project/admin/*` would I need `!project/admin` ? and would I place the `.gitignore` it in `projects/../` directory ? e.g. in the parent directory of `projects` ?

Comment: Yes, you need to specify the directory and what's inside, I couldn't find a way around this. The example I've written would go outside the `projects` directory but you could always add one inside which would spare you from repeating `projects` three times.

Comment: Just another thing, personally I prefer to keep only one `.gitignore` per project, that way I can be sure where to go.

Answer (score 6):

```
projects/*
!projects/admin
```

The `!` prefix before a line negates it; i.e. the directory or file given in that line will *not* be ignored.

Comment: would I place the `.gitignore` it in `projects/../` directory ? e.g. in the parent directory of `projects` ?

Comment: I usually use one ``.gitignore`` right at the root of the project, so yes.

Answer (score 1):

You can put a .gitignore file directly in the `projects` directory and it will only affect that directory.

So, in `projects/.gitignore`, just put:

```
admin
x
etc
```

Comment: In this way I need to update the `.gitignore` whenever a new project is added

Comment: @NeelBasu: This is true.  I prefer excluding things from source control *explicitly* rather than implicitly.

Answer (score -2):

You can add a .gitignore to each folder you don't want to track by running `touch project/x/.gitignore`. Git will then ignore the contents of each of those folders.

Comment: i don't think a blank .gitignore causes everything in the directory to be ignored.

Comment: A blank .gitignore in folders is actually used to have the OPPOSITE effect since git doesn't track (empty) folders and having a blank .gitignore is an easy way to add a file to start tracking the folder.